# How better off would we be If divine intervention happened during roman times

Tags: alternate-history

How better off would we be today if thousands of years ago during the roman empire, a "god"came down from the sky so that everyone could see them and instructed the human race to advance above all else and everybody listened and obeyed

When I say advance above all else I mean to achieve the best of everything possible. If it can be improved then improve it to the limits of your ability. Humans would do everything in their power to improve everything around them. An example would be choosing the most efficient way of doing things, using and improving the efficient means of doing things so that if lets just say a Phillips head screwdriver was better at screwing than a Flathead, then humans would only use Phillips heads and start improving their design further. Think of it as evolution of technology, where the ones who do the best job survive and are improved upon and those who do the same job but at a lesser efficiency are abandoned

**The questions**

Would things be more advanced today?

Would our quality of life be better or worse?

How might society be different today because of such an event?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is very broad, and also opinion based. Being "the best" means different things to different people/cultures. What you're asking is very subjective, affects hundreds of cultures, and pretty much every aspect of humanity's existence. There are military, religious, and even social implications. These sort of "what if" questions are out of scope for WB SE. Try to come up with a more tightly constrained universe, and asking questions about narrower aspects of it.

Comment: Some good reading: [Is WB a What If Site?](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site?rq=1) and [WB Risk Factors](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1)

Comment: Christians believe this has happened already in Roman times; just many people are not willing to listen to or understand the message.

Comment: Hello OP, I would recommend changing the title or extending it, so its is more visible what you are asking for. For example something like 'How better off would we be if there had been a real divine intervention 100 BC?'

Comment: "Best" depends on conditions.  To use your example, it's a lot easier to make flathead screws and screwdrivers than Phillps, so you get more screws, sooner and cheaper.  That's better if you have a lot of stuff that needs to be screwed together, and plenty of people to use the screwdrivers.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone dies.

Well, it varies depending on the morality you go on. If you opt that "Best for everyone" means no one dies, lives are saved to the point where Earth can no longer sustain life, and society collapse and dies.

If you say "Best average goodness", you will get a lot of "Mercy killing", stunted development as more resources are pushed to just get everything to everyone, and a lot of "[for the greater good](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheNeedsOfTheMany)" behavior

EDIT: By the above, I mean, you can't improve everything always. You have to focus on one thing at a time, and where you choose is the the best thing to improve on will largely shape the outcome. (medicine vs exploration vs preservation for example)

Answer (score 1):

First:
I would suggest reading Pax Romana by Johnathan Hickman

Second:
I think this is entirely dependent on the knowledge the god has. If he has magic or magic like technology then life could be perfect, we could be borg, we could be in the matrix. Really anything is possible.

If he's very smart but has no more knowledge than society does, he simply directs things perfectly. I would suggest going through a list of the most inventions and scientific break through and crunching them more tightly together as seems appropriate based on the reason the next advancement took X amount of years to come about.
This is probably pretty tedious and the premise is broad enough that you could probably wing it and retroactively justify the aesthetic you want.

Comment: The last paragraph is really interesting. I've ran scenarios on whether or not moon landing is possible within one generation given somebody whose seen the end from the beginning. The actual answer is beyond my reach.